# AlertDialog setButton was deprecated

Tags: android, eclipse

I use this code in my Eclipse Android project

```
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
});
```

But Eclipse is saying:

> This method was deprecated in API level 3. Use setButton(int,
> CharSequence, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener) with
> BUTTON_POSITIVE

## UPDATE AFTER 5 YEARS

This was my first step on entering a real programming adventure. It was like, ***oh I know how to do html website and this must be easy to code -native programming- so lets jump into it without reading any document.*** This is my first question on this awesome community which is a terrible question. One big suggestion that I can give to any beginner programmer which is; have some idea, dig some document and read open source about **how others made** before you jump into a new adventure. Patiently read the error that you encounter and try to realise what the **real** problem is. Thus you don't ask unnecessary question.

Comment: Wasn't that warning kind of super clear?

Comment: I wonder, does the code work nonetheless?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Java**

```
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
            alert.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

alert.show();
```

**Kotlin**

```
    var alert: AlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
    alert.setTitle("Error")
    alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!")
    alert.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
            //do your own idea.
            dialog, which -> finish() })
    alert.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

To make sure your dialogs match the design guidelines, the API now has 3 types of buttons for an AlertDialog: BUTTON_POSITIVE, BUTTON_NEUTRAL and BUTTON_NEGATIVE. This also provides correct positions for right to left support.

I would advice to create your `AlertDialog` with the builder pattern

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);//Context parameter
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do stuff
    }
});
builder.setMessage("some message");
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
```

More information on the `AlertDialog.Builder` can be found in the [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Comment: Thank you so much but it saying "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined" now

Comment: sorry, this was copied from some code. The parameter should be a context object

Answer (score 2):

```
alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Hello");
alertDialog.setMessage("Hai");
alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "hai", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thanks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Just wow this was almost my first question on programming. Btw thanks

Comment: Please provide explanations to your answer.

Comment: This Answer is used to directly show the Alert Dialog in your App

Answer (score 1):

You can use this but better use a AlertDialog.Builder next time.

```
   alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
            "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, yesListener);
alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, noListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setButton();` method accept three parameters

1. Button Type
2. Button Text
3. Message/OnClickListener     `// Message or clickListener`

Provide three params and it will work OK. If you do not need 3rd parameter you can pass null as

```
alertDialog.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
```

OR

```
alertDialog.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", (Message) null);
```

**If** you do not want to pass three parameters Use `AlertDialog.builder`'s method `setPositiveButton();`.