# why alertDialog.setButton onclickListner show error that no suitable method found

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

MainActivity

```
package com.example.dialog;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AlertDialog alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Term and Conditons");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_info_24);
alertDialog.setMessage("have you read all term and condition");
alertDialog.setButton("yes, I've read",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tes, you can proceed now..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Error

```
C:\Users\anonhake\AndroidStudioProjects\dialog\app\src\main\java\com\example\dialog\MainActivity.java:20: error: no suitable method found for setButton(String,<anonymous OnClickListener>)
alertDialog.setButton("yes, I've read",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
           ^
    method AlertDialog.setButton(int,CharSequence,Message) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method AlertDialog.setButton(int,CharSequence,OnClickListener) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method AlertDialog.setButton(int,CharSequence,Drawable,OnClickListener) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: I've found a post from 2015 stating that that method was deprecated. Have a look at this, maybe it'll help you resolve your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018587/alertdialog-setbutton-was-deprecated

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog)? There is no method with the signature `setButton(int, OnClickListener)`. You can see what methods are available in the docs or in the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't build your dialog in first line (`create()` call), use `AlertDialog.Builder` instance, set "possitive" and "negative" buttons on this (also title, message etc.), then call `create()` or even simpler `show()`

check out sample [HERE](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-alert-dialog-example)

```
// initial builder and msg setup
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Close app?").setTitle("Exit");

// can't close dialog with e.g. back button, must be picked on of buttons
builder.setCancelable(false); 

// buttons setup
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
        finish(); // closing Activity
    }  
});
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    
    }  
});
builder.show();
```

dialog will close automatically when any button clicked, the one with "Yes" will close whole `Activity`, "No" is empty and you will stay in (looks like empty) `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

As per error , it looks like method with parameter types that you are using is not there . So basically you have three choice to use

```
 1. setButton(int,CharSequence,Message)
 2. setButton(int,CharSequence,OnClickListener)
 3. setButton(int,CharSequence,Drawable,OnClickListener)
```